# Permission denied when tried to connect to an SSH server

Tags: android, ssh, permission-denied

I have installed a python server on my robot and also create a socket to robot successfully. Everything is looking fine but when I want to create a channel I have an error that says:

```
sending naocom/start.sh
W/System.err: bash: naocom/start.sh: Permission denied
```

here is where I tried to start connection and start python server with

```
 public Map<String, Integer> sendSSHCommands(String[] aCommands, String... aInput){

    // Connect to ssh server
    Session vSession = connectSSH();
    Map<String, Integer> vExitStatus = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    if( vSession != null){

        // execute commands
        for( int i=0; i < aCommands.length; i++ ){
            String cmd = aCommands[i];
            try{
                // open channel
                Channel vChannel = vSession.openChannel("naocom/start.sh");
                ChannelExec vChannelExec = (ChannelExec) vChannel;
                OutputStream vOutStream = vChannel.getOutputStream();
                vChannelExec.setCommand(cmd);
                vChannelExec.setOutputStream(System.out);
                vChannelExec.setErrStream(System.err);

                // connect
                Log.i(TAG, "sending " + cmd);
                vChannel.connect();

                // get user information
                SharedPreferences vPreferences = MainActivity.getPreferences();


                // wait for command to complete
                while( !vChannel.isClosed() ){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                };

                // add exit status
                vExitStatus.put( cmd, vChannel.getExitStatus() );
                vOutStream.close();
                vChannel.disconnect();

            } catch(JSchException e){
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // close ssh connection
        closeSSH(vSession);
    }

    return vExitStatus;
}
```

when I debuged my code I found it happend when start(); in Channel.java called

```
  public void connect() throws JSchException{
    connect(0);
  }

  public void connect(int connectTimeout) throws JSchException{
    this.connectTimeout=connectTimeout;
    try{
      sendChannelOpen();
      start(); //here i have an error
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      connected=false;
      disconnect();
      if(e instanceof JSchException) 
        throw (JSchException)e;
      throw new JSchException(e.toString(), e);
    }
  }
```